# Agenda em JSF com datatable possuindo dados de diferentes listas

Tags: java, primefaces, postgresql, jsf-2.2, jpa-2.0

Estou fazendo um software em JSF (2.2), primefaces e JPA com o banco Postgres. Eu preciso fazer uma agenda de contas a pagar com as seguintes colunas e seus dados:
Coluna antes de ontem com os dados: data vencimento, fornecedor e valor.
Coluna ontem com os dados: data vencimento, fornecedor e valor.
Coluna hoje com os dados: data vencimento, fornecedor e valor.
Coluna amanhã com os dados: data vencimento, fornecedor e valor.
Coluna depois de amanhã com os dados: data vencimento, fornecedor e valor.

São vários dados de consultas diferentes. A minha dúvida é como realizar essas consultas em um único datatable. Como vou fazer para saber que lista chamar nas colunas.

São essas as dúvidas.

Comment: São o mesmo objeto? Ou pra cada coluna você fez um objeto diferente?

Comment: Você pode trazer tudo em uma consulta só, e colocar os respectivos dados de acordo como você quer, provavelmente vai ser mais de um objeto que você vai precisar popular.

Comment: Então eu não cheguei a fazer por não saber como apresentar esses dados. Dai queria ver como faço para identificar a coluna antes de ontem tem que receber esse objeto a coluna ontem tem que receber esse objeto e assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um objeto auxiliar para usar na sua datatable, nesse objeto você coloca os objetos das coluna antes de ontem, de ontem, etc... Assim você faz um lista com esses objetos auxiliares e coloca no value da sua dataTable. Ai você decide oque colocar em cada coluna.

Comment: então as consultas retornam uma lista então fiz assim:
contas1 = new ContaPagarDao().listarAgenda("Antes de ontem");
        contas2 = new ContaPagarDao().listarAgenda("Ontem");
        contas3 = new ContaPagarDao().listarAgenda("Hoje");
        contas4 = new ContaPagarDao().listarAgenda("Amanhã");
        contas5 = new ContaPagarDao().listarAgenda("Depois de amanhã");
Seria isso? Para adicionar todos esses list em um único list como seria?

Comment: Pelo que código que você mostrou, parece que são todos objetos da mesma classe, então não teria problema colocar na mesma List.

Comment: Seria mais simples se cada um fosse uma tabela no banco de dados. Por exemplo: contas, anteontem, ontem. Essas tabelas teriam um relacionamento com a tabela contas, dessa forma você faria uma única consulta pra obter todos os dados

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Na verdade, não haveria diferença de dificuldade dentre estar em múltiplas tabelas ou estar em uma única tabela; o join seria extremamente parecido.